# Android Studio: Designer without gravity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I don't know how to describe this properly. I'm using Android Studio for the first time (Eclipse before, but due to some reasons I can't use Eclipse on the computer I'm at for some weeks now) and trying to use the implemented designer. The problem is, there are only nine places (top|left, top|right etc...) where you can place objects. Is there any "free mode"?

Answer (score 0):

Got it already. The solution is to morph the FrameLayout of the designer into a RelativeLayout (which Eclipse uses as default as it seems).

Comment: As far as I know Eclipse uses LinearLayout as default. But it is possible the designer automatically switches to different layouts if necessary.